# Generating a .bundle file with CMake on MAC OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I want to generate an executable in a `.bundle` file on `Mac OSX 10.6.8` using `CMake`. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(TESTProject)
SET(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME TEST)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(TEST MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(TEST PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
```

Then I call CMake:

```
CMake -G"Xcode" .
```

However, when I compile this program with `Xcode 3.2.1`, I constantly get a `TEST.app` file instead of a `TEST.bundle` file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The information at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Bundles_And_Frameworks suggests that `MACOSX_BUNDLE` indicates that the target is used to produce a bundled application (e.g., Test.app rather than a command line tool Test), rather than a `.bundle` bundle.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am more considering .bundle for plugins on MAC OSX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the BUNDLE_EXTENSION target property to get a different extension than the default. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:BUNDLE_EXTENSION

Also, I think .app is only the default for executable targets. For library or module targets, .bundle should be the default value.

Did you try with a library target?

Comment: Yes, I finally succeeded. It is a set of different commands with BUNDLE_EXTENSION and add_library (instead of add_executable). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Korchkidu Can you please let me know the exact commands and the order in which you wrote them. An example would be grand.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who runs across this and is trying to build a library .bundle, this worked for me on CMake 3.0:

```
add_library(Foo MODULE ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES BUNDLE TRUE)
```

The key is to use `MODULE` not `SHARED`. For some reason, CMake ignores the `BUNDLE` property otherwise.