# Build Unity native bundle with CMake on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, cmake

I have an Xcode project that builds a bundle that contains a library. I created the project using the following menu:

> New Project -> Framework & Library -> Bundle

To give a bit more context I want to create a [native plugin for Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html). At the moment the header is very simple and just contains a header and a source file.

I now want to be able to generate a similar project using CMake and I am struggling to make it work.

The CMake file I have boils down to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Plugin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES Plugin.cpp)
add_library(Plugin SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The above script builds a .dylib file and I would like to get it to build a .bundle file.

I found that [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_executable.html) has a MACOSX_BUNDLE option but it doesn't work for me because I want to bundle a library. There is also a target property called [BUNDLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/BUNDLE.html) but it doesn't seem to change anything to my project - it still creates a .dylib file when I would expect to get a .bundle file.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120951/generating-a-bundle-file-with-cmake-on-mac-osx) that seems to suggest a valid solution but I can't make it work for my project.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use CMake, but I have built a Unity native library for both iOS and OSX.   I use a build script to build for both platforms by calling `xcodebuild`.  It builds a static library for iOS and a dynamic library for OSX and when copying the built libraries into place, the `.dylib` is simply renamed to `.bundle`.

Here is my build script, if that helps:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT=UnityPlugin_UserDefaults.xcodeproj
CONFIGURATION=Release
BUILDDIR=build
OSXARCHIVEDIR=UserDefaults_OSX.xcarchive
IOSLIB=../Plugins/iOS/libUserDefaults.a
OSXLIB=../Plugins/UserDefaults.bundle

rm -rf $BUILDDIR $OSXARCHIVEDIR

for sdk in iphoneos iphonesimulator
do
    xcodebuild -project $PROJECT -configuration $CONFIGURATION -scheme UserDefaults_iOS -derivedDataPath $BUILDDIR -sdk $sdk build || exit 2
done

mkdir -p $(dirname $IOSLIB)
rm -f $IOSLIB
xcrun lipo \
    $BUILDDIR/Build/Products/$CONFIGURATION-iphoneos/libUserDefaults.a \
    $BUILDDIR/Build/Products/$CONFIGURATION-iphonesimulator/libUserDefaults.a \
    -output $IOSLIB \
    -create || exit 3

echo Created $IOSLIB:
file $IOSLIB

xcodebuild -project $PROJECT -configuration $CONFIGURATION -scheme UserDefaults_OSX -derivedDataPath $BUILDDIR -archivePath $OSXARCHIVEDIR -sdk macosx archive || exit 4

mkdir -p $(dirname $OSXLIB)
cp $OSXARCHIVEDIR/Products/usr/local/lib/libUserDefaults.dylib $OSXLIB || exit 5

echo Created $OSXLIB:
file $OSXLIB

rm -rf $BUILDDIR
```

The Xcode project contains a target for each platform with a *Scheme* used to define which to build.

Comment: I didn't know you could just rename the dynamic library to .bundle (at least in Unity). This is all new to me but I thought bundles and dynamic libraries were different things. It solves my problem so I'll accept the answer. Properly building a bundle from CMake will be the subject of another question :-)

Comment: @Clem Yes dynamic libraries and bundles are different, however Unity seems to treat them incorrectly it seems...

Answer (score 11):

With CMake :

```
add_library(Plugin MODULE ${SRCS})
set_target_properties(Plugin PROPERTIES BUNDLE TRUE)
```

will create `Plugin.bundle` folder with `Contents/MacOS/Plugin`

The BUNDLE property is described [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUNDLE.html).

Also, according to [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/24113/view.html) on Unity3D's forum, just renaming a .dylib into .bundle should also work.

In CMake, this would be:

```
set_target_properties(Plugin PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".bundle")
```

Comment: This is the minimum and clear explanation for creating bundle.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION: The "BUNDLE" properties does not appear to be known to CMake. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set_target_properties.html then https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties

Comment: @AngelGabriel  yes it is : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/BUNDLE.html

Comment: Apologies - you're absolutely right (I've looked in the bundle contents - everything is in place)